# characteristic equation: complex roots simplification

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am confused with how to simplify my characteristic equation

$D^{2} +9 = 0$

$\lambda_{1} = 3j, \lambda_{2} = -3j$

$y_{0} = C_{1}\cos(3t) + C_{2}\sin(3t)$

How does the above equation simplify to: $y_{0} = c\cos(3t + \theta)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Compare with $y_0 = c\cos(3t+\theta)=c\cos(3t)\cos(\theta)-c\sin(3r)\sin(\theta)$

To obtain:

$$c\cos(\theta)=C_1$$
$$c\sin(\theta)=C_2.$$

Square both equations and add them to obtain $c = \sqrt{C_1^2+C_2^2}$.

Assuming $C_1\neq 0$ (the case $C_1=0$ is easy to analyse) divide the second equation by the first equation to obtain $\tan(\theta)=\frac{C_2}{C_1}$.